# Error: Leaders not followed by proper glue

Tags: macros

I'm trying to compile the template of a resume, but I get the following errors:

```
"Use of \@ doesn't match its definition."
"Leaders not followed by proper glue"
"Undefined control sequence."
"Missing number, treated as zero."
"Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."
```

Isolating the line that gives me the error, I could write a minimal example that still gives me all the errors, except the first one:

```
\documentclass[a4papers,11pt]{article}

\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height #1 \hfill \kern\z@}

\begin{document}

\vhrulefill{0.9pt}

\end{document}
```

Although this example doesn't result in the first error, I get the

> Use of @ doesn't match its definition.

all over the place in the original file. What's going on? I use an old computer with an old version of TeX Live (2014), could this be related?

Comment: Probably by using `@` without enclose between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Maybe this helps as an explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: Thanks! A makeatletter at the beginning solved everything. Would you make an answer for me to vote for it?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If you feel I closed your question in error, please let me know. It seems to be a classic instance of where `\makeatletter` is needed to permit a macro that includes `@` in its name.